# JSP no me carga las imágenes al default path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Buenas estoy tratando de cargar imagenes a una carpeta predeterminada que creado en C:\img , ejecuto la app y todo va bien, veo el form, busco la imagen y al darle a submit este me redirecciona denuevo al form para continuar subiendo imagenes sin mensaje de error alguno. El problema es que voy a la carpeta donde debió guadarse la imagen ("C:\img") y no hay nada...

El index.jsp contiene el siguiente form

```
<form role="form" action="Upload.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="btn btn-success btn-file">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Browse <input type="file"
                name="file" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" name='submit'>submit</button>
        `
    </form>
```

Este form se comunica con mi archivo Upload.jsp para cargar las imágenes y guardarlas en una carpeta que he predeterminado en

> C:\img

Código de Upload.jsp:

```html
 <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>

    <%
       String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("User");
      File file ;
      int maxFileSize = 5000000 * 1024;
      int maxMemSize = 5000000 * 1024;
      ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
      String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

      String contentType = request.getContentType();
      if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

         DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
         
         factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);

         factory.setRepository(new File("C:\\img\\"));


   ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

   upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
    try{ 

     List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);


     Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

     while ( i.hasNext () ) 
     {
        FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
        if ( !fi.isFormField () )   
        {

        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
        String fileName = fi.getName();
        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

        if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
        file = new File( filePath + 
        fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
        }else{
        file = new File( filePath + 
        fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
        }
        fi.write( file ) ;

        request.setAttribute("Success", "Successfully Uploaded");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        }
     }

  }catch(Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
  }
      }else{
         request.setAttribute("Error", "Error!!");
        RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("/UploadFiles.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
      }
   %>
```

A continuación les muestro la estructura de mi proyecto con las librerias JAR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente mi archivo web.xml

```
<context-param>
<description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
<param-name>file-upload</param-name>
<param-value>
         C:\\img\\
</param-value>
```

Que está fallando? desde ya muchas gracias

**Solución**

Finalmente logre solucionar el problema cambiando la función `Upload.jsp` a un servle `upload.java` mucho mas simplificado. Dejo a continuación el código.

```html
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class upload
 */
@WebServlet("/upload")
@MultipartConfig
public class upload extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Recibe el <input type="file" name="file">
     String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.
     

    // InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
  
     File uploads = new File("C:\\img\\");
     File file = File.createTempFile("WebApp-", ".enc", uploads);
     try (InputStream fileContent1 = filePart.getInputStream()){
         Files.copy(fileContent1, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
         
         request.setAttribute("Correcto", "Archivo guardado con exito!");
         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
         rd.forward(request, response);
     
     }catch(Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error: "+ ex);
     }
     
 }
}
```

Comment: Agregale algunas líneas de Log (o System.out.println() para ver los datos te llegan y se procesan como vos esperas) por ejemplo si el while se ejecuta o no, los nombres de los archivos que va a grabar...

Comment: Ingrese distintos Systemout en distintas partes del código el resultado fue que  en la parte de `" request.setAttribute("Success", "Successfully Uploaded");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);"` devuelve un [java.lang.NullPointerException]

Comment: Entonces en algún lado tenés un NPE que debe estar cayendo en un catch. Fijate de ver donde cae, hace un print del stack trace y ahi te va a decir exacto cual es la linea que tiene el problema, y de ahi inferir cual es el objecto que es null cuando no debería serlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, finalmente lo solucione cambiando la función del archivo Upload.jsp a un servlet upload.java mas simplificado

Answer (score 0):

Solución planteada al final de la pregunta. En resumen se cambio la clase.jsp a un servlet mas simplificado en código.-